# PHP redirect to certain HTML file based on username

Tags: php, html

I have a small snippet of code that pulls information from a MySQL database based on a username entered in a text box. Right now this just redirects to one HTML page 'homepage1.html'.

But what I want it to do is to redirect to a different page based on the username entered for example: User1 -> homepage1.html.... User2 -> homepage2.html but still display the information in the div.

I am quite new to this so any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

PHP snippet in homepage1.html

```
<?php
   //check for a form submission
   if (isset ($_GET['username'])) {
$username = $_GET['username'];
$conn = mysqli_connect("**********", "**********", "**********") or die("cannot connect"); 
mysqli_select_db($conn, "*************") or die("cannot select DB");
$userquery = mysqli_query ($conn,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'" ) or die ("The query was not  found");
if (mysqli_num_rows($userquery) !=1 ) {
 die ("That username could not be found!");
}
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($userquery, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
$username = $row['username'];
$surname = $row['surname'];
$address = $row['address'];
$email = $row['email'];
$firstname = $row['firstname'];
$dob = $row['dob'];
}

?>
<h2><?php echo $firstname; ?> <?php echo $surname; ?> profile</h2><br>
<table>
 <tr><td>Firstname:</td><td><?php echo $firstname; ?></td></tr>
 <tr><td>Lastname:</td><td><?php echo $surname; ?></td></tr>
 <tr><td>Date of Birth:</td><td><?php echo $dob; ?></td></tr>
 <tr><td>Address:</td><td><?php echo $address; ?></td></tr>
 <tr><td>E-mail:</td><td><?php echo $email; ?></td></tr>

</table>
    <?php
    } else die ("You need to specify a username!");
?>
```

---

Index.html form

```
<form action="homepage1.html" method="GET">

<input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Username" name="username">
<input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" name="password">
<input type="submit" class="button" id="submit" name="submit" value="Sign in!">

</form>
```

Comment: on what basis do you want to redirect user... I mean how many users are there in database are you having different pages for each user and are you trying to redirect to there page? Could you explain a little more

Comment: If you want to submit the form to a different server script, you need to do that in the client using JavaScript.

Comment: Do you have your server configured to process `.html` files with PHP? Normally PHP code is in `.php` files.

Comment: Hello guys,

Yes my server is configured to process .html files with PHP.

Also, it is only a prototype so I only need to to redirect to either one of two pages.
There will be 2 users on the database, with only 2 pages 1 for each user.

So in total there will be, 
Login page(just a simple MySQL query not exactly a login.
and an additional 2 pages (1 for each user)

So I want the query to pull information from the DB and display it but also to redirect each user to a different page depending on what the username is.

I hope that makes things clearer? 

Thank you for your help